# How to change TaigaUI tab color?

Tags: css, angular, frontend

How to change color theme including the background color and active element color of `<tui-tabs>`. (in an Angular project)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default theme style using **:host ::ng-deep** method.To do this you have to get the desired element class by inspecting in your browser and use that class in your style sheet in this way to override the default theme style

:host ::ng-deep.element-class-name{
your style here ...
}